# Problema con comandos npm y angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, cmd, npm, instalacion

He venido presentando ciertos problemas con npm y angular, debido a que cuando quiero ejecutar algún comando (incluso para conocer la versión), está demasiado lento y se demora mucho en cargar.

Actualmente manejo angular en su versión 11.0.1, npm 6.14.8 , y node 14.15.0

Ya he probado instalar otra versión de angular, y reinstalar node, pero sigo con el mismo problema. Realmente es frustrante tener que esperar tanto tiempo, pues no he podido ser productivo.

Agradezco mucho si alguien me puede colaborar con dicho problema, pues ya he consultado pero no he tenido solución efectiva.

Que tengan buen día

Comment: Comprueba la velocidad de internet y/o si ne se actualizo tu ordenador, tenia los mismos sintomas hace unos dias,

Comment: @TomaszVizaint el internet está bien, pues solo sucede con npm y Angular. Instalé de nuevo los paquetes desde cero, debido a le hice un formateo al PC, no sé qué pueda estar fallando.

Comment: Hm, Hecho una prueba con un proyecto de prueba que tengo y no note ningun cambio, Tu los has hecho global ?

Comment: @TomaszVizaint sí, así es. Lo curioso es que también pasa con npm, no sé si este gestor sea el culpable de que no se ejecute algún comando de Angular en un mínimo tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a que no obtuve una respuesta prudente, me tomé la tarea de realizar una investigación exhaustiva y resulta que el problema no tiene que ver con los paquetes de node ni las dependencias de npm, sino con Windows Defender que, por alguna razón hace demorada la ejecución de los comandos. Mi problema se solucionó con los siguientes pasos:

1. Entré a Configuración de Windows Defender / Protección contra virus y amenazas / Configuración de Protección contra virus y amenazas
2. Busqué el encabezado de "Exclusiones" e ingresé a "Agregar o quitar exclusiones"
3. Estando en esa ventana, agregué dos exclusiones, una para node y la otra para npm, los cuales se encontraban en:

nodejs:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

npm:

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

donde  corresponde al nombre del directorio de tu usuario. Asegúrate de habilitar la vista de "elementos ocultos" (https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/mostrar-archivos-ocultos-0320fe58-0117-fd59-6851-9b7f9840fdb2)

4. Por último ejecuté cualquier comando de npm y ng, y todo funciona correctamente.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de gran ayuda para personas que estén pasando por este problema!!!